# How did the cucumber get detected at the airport?

Tags: plot-explanation, this-is-spinal-tap

In This Is Spinal Tap, one of the guys from the band has a cucumber in his groin region, but it was detected at the airport.

[image]

I know there is no vegetable detectors like metal detectors.

How did he get caught?

Comment: What kind of solid silver cucumbers have you been eating?

Comment: ["It's not a cucumber," Derek has pointed out. "A cucumber is all pimply."](http://www.spinaltap.com/atozed/TAP00613.HTM)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Because of the aluminum foil](http://www.spinaltap.com/atozed/TAP00010.HTM):

> Wrapped around a zucchini by roadie Moke during the 1982 tour so that Derek could put the expand back in his Spandex. Prompted after David and Nigel suggested on the tour bus that there "was something missing in terms of thrust" in Derek's "power zone." Nigel: "There should be a bit of projection." During the filming of "This is Spinal Tap," **Derek was asked to remove the appendage by an airport security guard after he set off the metal detector.** In the commentary on the Special Edition DVD, he explained that the Moke wrapped the vegetable to prevent it from rotting against Derek's thighs.